# How to Get Piece of Path in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to get **tokenKey** piece of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in `GetTokenKeyGuard.ts` file.

I tried like this but doesnt work :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

    localStorage.setItem('token_key', route.queryParams.tokenKey);

    return true;
  }
```

Because tokenKey is not query param (not `localhost/path?tokenKey=blabla`).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'auth/login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'auth/login/:tokenKey', canActivate: [GetTokenKeyGuard], component: LoginComponent },
];
```

How to get **tokenKey** variable of path in `GetTokenKey.ts` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

Not `queryParams`. It is only `params`.

```
localStorage.setItem('token_key', route.params.tokenKey);
```